# ¿Cómo ordenar numéricamente columnas en un data.frame en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un data.frame grande (98 columnas y 120 filas)
Mi intención es ordenar las columnas (cada una es un número del tipo "1474091564.recal", "2007828340.recal", etc.) por el orden numérico de los números iniciales que las componen para más adelante poder combinar con otro data.frame.

Comment: Bienvenido Pablo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tenemos algo así:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(20), ncol = 5))

colnames(df) <- c("3.recal", "2.recal", "1474091564.recal", "2007828340.recal", "1.recal")
df

    3.recal    2.recal 1474091564.recal 2007828340.recal    1.recal
1 0.9238188 0.01929293       0.94533244        0.2356905 0.49984116
2 0.7710084 0.10452518       0.06055658        0.3959334 0.04912883
3 0.2231289 0.34398224       0.40580063        0.4881912 0.90761028
4 0.4562247 0.36736892       0.91107994        0.9985666 0.69226913
```

---

Para ordenar numéricamente las columnas, primero hay que "extraer" la parte numérica de los nombre de columna, si el patrón es el que mencionaste, podríamos dividir cada cadena por el `.` y quedarnos solo con la primera parte, por ejemplo:

```
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(colnames(df) , '[.]'), `[[`, 1))

[1] 1474091564 2007828340          1
```

---

`strsplit()` divide cada cadena por el `.`, usamos el patrón `[.]` para indicar el literal `.` por que en expresiones regulares este caracter tiene otro uso. Luego simplemente aplicamos la extracción mediante los `[[` del primer elemento de cada lista.

Y ahora sí podremos ordenar el `data.frame`:

```
df[, order(as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(colnames(df) , '[.]'), `[[`, 1)))]

     1.recal    2.recal   3.recal 1474091564.recal 2007828340.recal
1 0.49984116 0.01929293 0.9238188       0.94533244        0.2356905
2 0.04912883 0.10452518 0.7710084       0.06055658        0.3959334
3 0.90761028 0.34398224 0.2231289       0.40580063        0.4881912
4 0.69226913 0.36736892 0.4562247       0.91107994        0.9985666
```

Comment: En mi caso no son filas lo que quiero ordenaro, son columnas.

Comment: ok, revisa mi última edición.